# tools inside updatepanel causing full postback asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, triggers, postback, html-select

I have a problem with my online order form, i have put all my dropdownlists and buttons inside updatepanel but when i select something in a dropdownlist or when i press a button whole page post back...please help me! This is a my code:`
                    
                    
                        
                            <%----%>

```
                            <strong><asp:ImageButton 
                                ID="btnExcel0" runat="server" AlternateText="Export to Excel" Height="30px" 
                                ImageUrl="/images/excel_icon1.png" onclick="btnExcel_Click" TabIndex="14" />
                            </strong>&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
                             <input type="image" runat ="server" id ="Image1" src ="/images/images.jpg" onclick="javascript:CallPrint('divPivot1')" title="Print" />

                            <br />
                            <div id= "divPivot1">
                            <asp:GridView ID="OrderGridView" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
                                BorderStyle="None" CellPadding="3" DataKeyNames="Article" 
                                EmptyDataText="&quot;No product added...&quot;" Font-Size="Small" HorizontalAlign="Left" 
                                OnPageIndexChanging="OrderGridView_PageIndexChanging" PageSize="20" 
                                TabIndex="15" Width="866px" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" 
                                BorderWidth="1px">
                                <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#336699" />
                                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#336699" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                <PagerSettings FirstPageText="First" LastPageText="Last" />
                                <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#336699" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                <RowStyle ForeColor="#336699" Font-Size="Small" />
                                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#669999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
                                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#007DBB" />
                                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
                                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#00547E" />
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Update Quantity" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="80">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox" runat="server" Width="90" />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>
        br />
                                <br />
                               <asp:Label ID="lblsum" runat="server" CssClass="style19" Text="Sum Total"></asp:Label>
                            <br />
                               <asp:Label ID="sum" runat="server" CssClass="style19"></asp:Label>
                            <br />
                            </div>
                            <strong><asp:ImageButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Height="28px" 
                                    ImageUrl="/images/bt_Delete.jpg" onclick="btnDelete_Click" 
                                    OnClientClick="return DeleteConfirmation();" TabIndex="13" Width="106px" />
                                </strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;<asp:ImageButton ID="btnUpdate" 
                                    runat="server" Height="28px" ImageUrl="/images/btUpdate.jpg" Width="106px" 
                                    OnClientClick="return UpdateConfirmation();" 
                                    onclick="btnUpdate_Click" />
                            <asp:TextBox ID="username" runat="server" Height="16px" Visible="False" 
                                    Width="128px"></asp:TextBox>
                            <br />

                            <asp:Label ID="Label16" runat="server" Text="Notes:" ForeColor="#336699"></asp:Label>

                            <br />
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Height="101px" TabIndex="10" 
                                TextMode="MultiLine" Width="860px"></asp:TextBox>
                            <br />
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:ImageButton 
                                ID="btnSend" runat="server" ImageUrl="/images/mail2.jpg" 
                                onclick="Button1_Click"  AlternateText="Send your Order"
                                TabIndex="11" Height="75px" Width="90px"/><strong><asp:ImageButton 
                                ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" Height="66px" 
                                ImageUrl="/images/logout.png"  Width="56px" 
                                 onclick="ImageButton1_Click" />
                            </strong>
                            <br />
                            <strong>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label18" runat="server" style="color: #336699" 
                                Text="*Delete Product from List: Check the products which you want to remove from your list and press the delete button."></asp:Label>
                            </strong>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnExcel0" />
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ImageButton1" />
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="code" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="type" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="p" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="dem" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="quant" EventName="TextChanged" />
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAdd" />
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnDelete" />
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUpdate" />
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSend" />
                    </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot see the code of your drop down lists, i caught myself in same problem once.
I set the drop down list AutoPostBack= True and define a method in selected index changed.
So make sure you did not doing the same and upload your complete code.

Comment: <asp:DropDownList ID="code" runat="server" 
                                    BackColor="White" Height="22px" 
                                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="code_SelectedIndexChanged" TabIndex="4" 
                                    ViewStateMode="Enabled" Width="150px" AutoPostBack="True">
                                    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
This is one of my dropdown lists

Comment: I dont know why, but i cannot upload my complete code.... I have 4 dropdownlists , 4 buttons and a gridview inside the updatepanel.

Comment: so as i have said your drop down contains the both things i.e. AutoPostBack = true and event on selected index changed
so you need to remove them in order to avoid post-backs
are you performing anything inside selected index change event of dropdownlist ??

Comment: protected void code_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            p.Items.Clear();
            p.Items.Add(new ListItem("--Select P--"));
            
            type.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
            OrdersDataContext db = new OrdersDataContext();
            var selectType = (from t in db.typeTs
                              where (t.codeId == Convert.ToInt32(code.SelectedItem.Value))
                              select t).OrderBy(t => t.type);
            type.DataSource = selectType;
            type.DataTextField = "type";

Comment: type.DataValueField = "id";
            type.DataBind();
            if (type.Items.Count > 2)
            {
                type.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                type.Enabled = false;
                dem.Enabled = false;
            }
        }

Comment: this is my code in for Code_dropdownlist, my project works like this: client select the code of the product after this next dropdownlist, which is the type of product, activated with types that are available only for this code, if you want you can check my project smirdex.gr/OrderForm2.2/LogIn.aspx use for username abins_Aimilios and pass: 5a>=nBiQR?MDe+   Thank you very much!!!!

Comment: ok, dear @TSACHIDOU DIANA i got your problem
i was having the 100% same problem
what i do to solve this? I use the control of cascading dropdown of ajax toolkit, you can find many tutorial if you browse for it. So i populate my dropdowns via this control and not using the selected index changed. So look for cascading drop down control of ajax control toolkit and i am sure your problem will be solved!

Comment: dear zeeshan i made the changes that you suggested but i have an another problem, all the dropdownlists are empty! Can you please help me!

Comment: dropdownlists are empty after using cascading drop down?

Comment: yes, on the local machine it works great, but when i deployed it on the server, the dropdownlists are empty... if you want you can check it...maybe i need to make some changes in the config file..i have inserted <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules>
      <remove name="ScriptModule"/>
      <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </modules>

Comment: <handlers>
      <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
      <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory"/>
      <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices"/>
      <remove name="ScriptResource"/>
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>

Comment: <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </handlers></system.webServer>

Comment: honestly i did not understand most of the code you write in your comments :) I am not the one who deployed products on live.
In my case i pick my connection string from Web.Config and nothing else, i don't know if there are some changes required to make product live.
Sorry dear but i am not the correct person to answer this!